# I got parse warning when using the Panda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, stanford-nlp, spacy, knowledge-graph

I am working to create the knowledge graph by using unstructured data using spacy, panda and much more libraries of python but the thing is that i encounter with warning which is parse warning.

Lets see this code and am using jupyter notebook to first extract the triples that is subject, object and predicate then am using networkx and matplot library to make the knowledge.

```
unstructured_text = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\NLPtoKG\\AbhayaKumar.csv", sep="NaN")
unstructured_text.shape
```

And i got this warning in my jupyter that is shown below

```
F:\MyProjectOntology\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.return func(*args, **kwargs)(118, 1)
```

I don't understand why this warning will be there after executing the code and if you guys knows how to convert text file to csv then python then do let me know because am very new to python.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pandas has a builtin parser for CSV (called 'c' engine) and there is a Python implementation of such parser (called 'Python' engine). The message should then be rather clear.

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet before doing complicated things with Python.

Comment: Sorry your logic didn't work for me @MichaelButscher

Comment: Why does your file end in ".csv" when the separator is "NaN" instead of a comma?

Comment: @jjramsey when i was using comma in sep then i got errors. like this F:\MyProjectOntology\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\python_parser.py in _alert_malformed(self, msg, row_num)
    720         """
    721         if self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.ERROR:
--> 722             raise ParserError(msg)
    723         elif self.on_bad_lines == self.BadLineHandleMethod.WARN:
    724             base = f"Skipping line {row_num}: "

ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 47, saw 20

Comment: Looks like in your CSV file, the number of fields per line isn't constant. That's not going to work with Pandas, and changing your separator will almost certainly not fix your underlying problem.

Comment: @jjramsey if you have any suggestion like i have unstructured text file now rather than pandas then what function can i use?

Comment: If your CSV file represents a ragged data structure (where each row is expected to have a different number of fields), then I would suggest using Python's `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You got the warning

ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (`separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex`); you can `avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'`.return func(*args, **kwargs)(118, 1)

So, try this instead -

```
pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Hp\\Desktop\\NLPtoKG\\AbhayaKumar.csv", sep="NaN", engine='python')
```

Comment: Thanks @MT54 your tip works for me and listen what if we include text file in this function?